# Delete a file after download it using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using Node.js and I need to delete a file after user download it. Is there any way to call a callback method after pipe process ends, or any event for that purpose?

```
exports.downloadZipFile = function(req, res){
    var fileName = req.params['fileName'];
    res.attachment(fileName);
    fs.createReadStream(fileName).pipe(res); 

    //delete file after download             
};
```

Comment: `fs.unlink(fileName, callBack);`

Comment: @Qix I have googled it, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: @Qix Yes, but that search doesn't have the answer I need, if you want I can vote down all your questions and answers... so try to help instead of vote down.

Comment: @Ragnar that is called [serial downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting) and is dealt with automatically by the system. Secondly, the answer to your questions is all over Google. In the future, spend a little more time searching and save a little more time in return.

Comment: Qix is an example of why people are leaving stack overflow

Comment: for the record i didnt find the answer by googling but i did find this question which has helped me.  perhaps if i already knew the answer i'd know what to google for.  thanks for asking Ragnar

Comment: Qix, I google'd and got this question. I think we just divided by zero.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can call `fs.unlink()` on the `finish` event of `res`.

Or you could use the `end` event of the file stream:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
file.on('end', function() {
  fs.unlink(fileName, function() {
    // file deleted
  });
});
file.pipe(res);
```

Comment: is there an equivalent way to do this with Koa? `ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(filename)` is what I was doing before, but i'd like to delete the file on 'end' using your method