# Couldn't serve a file after deleting with unlink()

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, fs, unlink

I am building an image compressor (with node,react) where after serving the compressed image by `res.download()` I want to delete the file for saving space. But if I put `await unlink(path)` after `res.download(path)` download fails in the client side and show errors in the server. **How can I achieve successful deletion without failing to send the file to the client?**
**My code in the backend:**

```
app.get('/download/:imageName', async (req,res)=>{
let imageName = req.params.imageName
let path = 'uploads/'+imageName;

const compressedImage = await imagemin([path], {
    destination: "compressed",
    plugins: [
      imageminPngquant({
        quality: [0.6, 0.8]
      }),
      imageminMozjpeg(),
      imageminGifsicle({lossy: 70}),
      imageminSvgo({
        plugins: extendDefaultPlugins([
            {name: 'removeViewBox', active: false}
        ])
        })
    ]
  });

   await res.download(process.cwd()+"/"+compressedImage[0].destinationPath)
   let compressedPath = 'compressed/'+path
   await unlink(compressedPath,(err)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(compressedPath+ " hase been deleted")
    })
})
```

***Thanks***

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27951092/delete-a-file-after-download-it-using-nodejs) ?

Comment: This link solves the problem. Thanks